# Random Forest in R with categorical attributes

Tags: r

I am trying to use RandomForest with categorical attributes in R, but I have a little problem: it doesn't work. This message appears, and I don't know how to solve it.

> Warning message in randomForest.default(m, y, ...):
>
> “The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?”Warning message in data.matrix(x):
>
> “NAs introduced by coercion”Warning message in data.matrix(x):
>
> “NAs introduced by coercion”Warning message in data.matrix(x):
>
> ...
>
> “NAs introduced by coercion”Warning message in mean.default(y):
>
> “argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA”

I'm using R through Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda.
All my attributes are nominal and there isn't any way to convert it to numerical without losing some information, I would prefer to use them as categorical rather than convert them.

I've checked the parameters of RandomForest function but it doesn't appear anything to point the algorithm to work with nominal attributes. I wonder if there's a way to make it run.

Comment: first do `y <- as.factor(y)`, then run your randomForest.

Comment: Thank you!

Now, appears this other message, even thought the RandomForest works:



>Warning message in randomForest.default(m, y, ...):

>“The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?”

What does this means? why there only five responses? It is because I only have 2 classes?